# Tracker.autorun not firing if it has a limit in the database query

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm having issues getting a Tracker.autorun to work when I have a limit function in a collection  find.

The function is

```
  Tracker.autorun(function () {
    console.log("sparkline Tracker.autorun called");

    var data = Infolite.find({
    }, {
      //limit: HS_CONFIG['no_sparkline_history'],
    }).fetch();
```

As it is, the function works fine, as soon as I uncomment the limit it never gets fired.

This is in its own template (to do with graphs) and is meant to be looking at a subset of data from a larger dataset.

The publication is

```
    Meteor.publish('History', function() {
  return Infolite.find({}, {
    sort: {_id: -1}, 
    limit: HS_CONFIG['no_generation_history'], 
    fields: {
      "a": 1,
      "c": 1,
      "g": 1, 
      "p": 1,
      "w": 1,
      "n": 1,
      "s": 1,
      "t": 1,
      "cs": 1,
      "di": 1,
      "ti": 1,
      "wd": 1,
      "tp": 1,
      "pr": 1,
    },
  });
```

where HS_CONFIG['no_generation_history'] is much larger than HS_CONFIG['no_sparkline_history'].  I have tried this with numbers directly in the limits so its not the config parameters causing issues.

Any ideas why this wouldn't get fired with the limit in place?

Comment: If I remember correctly, reactive computations are supposed to always run at least once, even if there's no reactive data. So you should at least see once `"sparkline Tracker.autorun called"`. Are you absolutely sure it is declared correctly? Maybe you moved it inside another function that doesn't get run properly, or another file of a package you didn't add, ...

Comment: and If I'm correct `limit` without `sort` is not reactive, check by adding `sort`, wild guess

Comment: Thankyou.. that did it. It was the missing sort. Added sort{_id: -1} and were all good. Please put this in as an answer and I'll tick it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your `Tracker.autorun` is throwing an exception. `Tracker.autorun` is always run initially, but from http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Tracker-autorun

> If the initial run of an autorun throws an exception, the computation is automatically stopped and won't be rerun.

I don't know if `limit` without `sort` causes an exception, but check your logs - `limit` certainly makes more sense with some kind of `sort`.

Also: If your `_id` are just integers, a `-1` sort makes sense for the latest, however if they are Mongo ids, you might be better off using a date field.